# Create a multilevel dropdown dynamically in React and get the value of selected submenu in dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

How would i create a multilevel dropdown dynamically and get the selected submenu velue.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `state` and updating it with selected `event.target.value`.This is working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: ""
  };
  selectHandler = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ selectedOption: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    let data = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
    return (
      <select
        onChange={(event) => this.selectHandler(event)}
        value={this.state.selectedOption}
      >
        {data.map(value => (
          <option value={value} key={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Hi @Avinash thank you.I have already done this but i need multilevel DropDown.